# VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4258: Android/view/View;.setAlpha (F)V

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager

I am getting this error:-

```
VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4258: Landroid/view/View;.setAlpha (F)V, VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4276: Landroid/view/View;.setTranslationX (F)V
```

this message in my logcat:-

```
Could not find method android.view.View.setTranslationX, referenced from method com.learning.animation.ZoomOutPageTransfer.transformPage.
```

I am trying to add `ZoomOut` page transfer animation using `viewpager` and for this I follow [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) link for Zoom out Page transfer, my application is running but it is not zooming out the page as it is shown in the above mentioned link to be.Please if anyone know the solution kindly tell.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question should not be tagged with java-me

Answer (score 0):

setTranslationX method is available only on android 3.0 ( api level 11) and up. Are sure you're using device/emulator with proper android version?